# Java output/input in an unexpected loop, even though I didn't intentionally put it in a loop

Tags: java

I'm taking a java course, and in my function I have a print statement/input that keeps continuously displaying even though I didn't put it in loop. Below is my function and my output. Any ideas what might be causing this issue? -- Thank you!

```
private void dologin() {
    
    int count = employeeList.size();
    loggedIn = false;
    
    //scanner opened
    Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in ); 
    
    System.out.println("Please enter your login name: "); 
    currentUser = sc.next(); 
    
    for (int i=0; i < count; ++i) {
        if(currentUser == employeeList.get(i).getLogin()) { 
            currentID = employeeList.get(i).getID() ;
            System.out.println("Welcome! You are logged in!"); 
            loggedIn = true;
        } else
            System.out.println("Log in not found. Redirecting to the main menu."); 
    }
    
    //scanner closed
    sc.close();
}
```

Output:
Payroll Menu
1. Log In 
2. Enter employees
3. List Employees
4. List employees
5. Terminate employees
6. Pay employees 
0. Exit system
Please enter a selection number:
1
Please enter your login name: 
mfk
Please enter your login name: 
mfk
Please enter your login name: 
mfk
Please enter your login name: 
mfk
Please enter your login name:

```
public void doMenu()  { 
    
    //scanner opened
    Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in ); 

    //prints menu 
    System.out.println(menu);

    //prompts selection and scans in selection
    System.out.println("Please enter a selection number: ");
    int selection = sc.nextInt();

    do { 
        switch (selection) { 
            case 0: 
                //writeFile();
                break; 
            case 1: 
                dologin(); 
                break; 
            case 2: 
                newEmployee(); 
                break; 
            case 3: 
                listEmployees();
                break; 
            case 4: 
                changeEmployee(); 
                break; 
            case 5: 
                terminateEmployee(); 
                break;
            case 6: 
                payEmployees(); 
                break; 
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, try again."); 
        }
            
    }while(selection!=0); 

    //Scanner is closed
    sc.close();

}
```

Comment: Whatever is causing it is not in the code you posted.

Comment: `sc.close();` is not good.  Do not close stdin.  Also should return after finding a user i.e. after `loggedIn = true;`

Comment: Show where you call `dologin()`

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas if it's a system.in/out issue or scanner issue? My code has lots of parts so I didn't want to post the whole thing. I'm not sure where to look. Since I'm a  novice I'm a bit lost. I thought I did everything right but clearly not!

Comment: I will edit my post with where it's called. thank you!

Comment: In general, you should avoid posting parts of your program.  This just leads to issues where it's unclear where the error is, and it also makes it hard for someone else who has the same problem to make use of the answer.  Instead, you should compile a [mre].

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong thanks for the tip! This is my first time posting to stack overflow. Your tip makes sense and I'll do that next time.

Comment: `currentUser == employeeList.get(i).getLogin()` isn't going to work in any case.  Using double-equals on strings almost always gives you the wrong answer.  Use `String.equals()` instead.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you! I had a feeling that part was going to give me issues too. It's for an arrayList. Do you know the correct syntax for using getters for array lists, while in a for loop?

Comment: @ScaryWombat what's the CRLF?

Comment: @mak95: They mean "new-line," as in `\n`.  CRLF is an old typewriter term meaning "Carriage Return, Line Feed."  I'm surprised anyone still uses it.

Comment: Also as mentioned above do not close the scanner.  You will never be able to read from it again unless you restart you program.

Comment: @Scary Wombat . Ah I see, thank you. Any tips for avoiding that problem?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, thank you, I apologize for my naivety, but how come I don't have to do that for other portions of my program or other programs in the past? usually it just takes one sc. line and I'm good to go. Is there something different about this case?

Comment: @mak95 Sorry you are calling `next` not `nextLine` please ignore my comments about CRLF

Comment: @ScaryWombat okay no worries. So do you think the rest of that function isn't being completed because of the syntax of my for loop condition? I'm not exactly sure of the right syntax for getting things from arraylists (first time implementing one). One person said to do String.equals(), but not sure if there's more to it.

Comment: As @RickyMo says below, your never prompt again for a new selection within your loop, so it will always be `1` and as you have closed your scanner, you will never be able to get new input anyway.  Fix these two items.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I made the changes and now I'm getting this error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: @scarywombat the error comes after "Enter a selection number:", with no opportunity to enter a menu selection, so it doesn't get to the dologin() function now

Comment: I can not imagine what you are doing

Comment: @scaryWombat I discovered the problem. I didn't delete the sc.close() for both functions. I only deleted it for one of them. --- Thank you for all your help. I'm new to programming so thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do{}while()` is a loop. You are looping while `selection != 0`. As you input `1` and assign to `selection` and never change it, sure it will loop infinitely.

Comment: @RickyMo thank you for your response. isn't this typically how switch case is done though? At least that's how I've done it. so I figured it would dologin(), then reach the break statement and exit the do while loop.

Comment: @mak95 the `break;` statement within a `switch` only breaks the `switch`, not breaking the loop outside it.